# navigation menu which stays on top

Tags: website-design

In some websites like facebook, the blue bar which shows notifications, messages, friend requests etc. stays static when we scroll down through the page. How to achieve this in a website? Did facebook used css, jQuery or something else

Answer (score 1):

It's achieved by utilising the `position:fixed` css style